# Is there a place where we can see which Microsoft's KB replaces which Microsoft's KB?

Tags: patching

Do you If there is a simple listing of which KB replaces which KB in Microsoft development because every report from Microsoft explain one by one which KB replaces which KB, but I can't find a place where this will be all gathered.

Microsoft Report Example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/security/bulletin/ms13-002)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a file you could download, mssecure.xml which contained all this info. It was used by Microsoft Baseline Security Analyser 1, which is now long retired. Unfortunately, there is no replacement from Microsoft ([info](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/6f7a3fec-2687-4365-98ec-f2741e73abda/xml-file-whick-contains-a-list-of-all-microsoft-bulletins?forum=MBSA)).

The information you need is contained in the [Nessus plugins](http://www.tenable.com/plugins/) and you could probably write a script to parse them and summarise the info. Although doing that may be a violation of the Nessus license.